# Use Google keyword planner inside Google AdWords, without creating ads?

Tags: seo, google, google-adsense, sem, google-keyword-tool

I want to use google keyword planner to check the keyword strength and reach, other details. So I decided to use Google keyword planner.

I created an account in Google AdWords, but it is asking for business name and website.  I filled that in with sample data. After that, everything leads to creating an ad.  At the end, it asking for payment information.

It is saying I should create an ad, but I don't want to create an ad, I just want to use the keyword planner, and run some experiments on it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this url https://adwords.google.com/um/Welcome/Expert , just fill with appropriate details , no need of card details .

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing same problem after Google AdWords Express launch. Someone give me this link to visit keyword planner:

https://adwords.google.com/aw/keywordplanner/home

Comment: really thank you friend . when i click this link it will redirected to https://adwords.google.com/express/plus/Plus?__u=****&__c=****&authuser=0&__b=*****#manage  .Here **** is some numbers ,  i think this number is my account id or some thing that's why i hide this number using *** . I will up vote your answer for the quick reply .

Comment: I think you have to fill out your account information first abilash. Once that's done the link posted by Al Muheet should work